# DateTime Conversion in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I converted some string values to `datetime` as below:

```
'20131018'
'20130917'
```

by using

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, @date, 101)
```

I got the following

```
'2013-10-18 00:00:00.000'
'2013-09-17 00:00:00.000'
```

How would I remove the timepart of the values?

Comment: In SQL Server **2008**, you'll get `DATE` datatypes for just that - date-only. 2005 only has `DATETIME` and those values always have a time portion included.

Comment: Does the time component break anything, or is just visually annoying?

Comment: CONVERT(DATE, @date, 101) will do what u want

Comment: @StingyJack its visually annoying haha

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) where expression will be your timestamp string and start will be 1 and length will be length of "yyyy-mm-dd" i.e. 10.
for more reference please check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Check what said by "marc_s". Just use DATE instead of DATETIME.This will be better option.

Comment: True, `DATE` would be the better choice here - but that datatype is **NOT YET** available in SQL Server **2005** that the OP is using ....

Comment: @ marc_s -- then we can use substring I think as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Have some code I made. If you can figure out how to make this faster or better let me know! ;)

```
case --Format date into YYYYMMDD with placeholder 0's 
    when (CAST(DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as int ) < 10) AND (CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as int) < 10) 
    then CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(4)) 
        +'0'+ LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))))
        +'0'+LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))))
    when (CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as int) < 10) 
    then CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(4)) 
        +'0'+LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))))
        +CAST(DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))
    when (CAST(DATEPART(DD, DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as int ) < 10) 
        then CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(4)) 
            + CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))
            +'0'+LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))))
    else CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(4)) 
        +CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))
        +CAST(DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(day, 7, <DATE>)) as CHAR(2))
end
```

Here's how it works. Put that after SELECT. Do a Find and Replace with  and put your date in there. It checks the number of digits in the month and day, then inserts a 0 or two into the string when appropriate. I saved this block of code so that it would be easy to use when I encounter this problem. Hope it helps!

--EDIT-- It occurs to me, this might be the reverse of what you want to do...